# Can "#pragma omp parallel for " be used inside a loop?

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

Can "#pragma omp parallel for" be used inside a loop in the following form:

```
For (i=0;i<...;.i+=1) 
  { #pragma omp parallel for
      for(j=0;j<...;j+=1) 
       { Some code.....}
```

- Will this just parralelize the loop on 'j' ?

Thanks on advence !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be used like that. But compiler directives have to be on a line of their own

```
for( ... )
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for( ...
//..
```

Also, this will indeed only execute the inner loop in parallel. If you need both loops to execute in parallel you need a second `#pragma omp parallel for` above the outer loop.

Comment: We need to note in this implementation the fact that the 'for' on the outside waits for the end of the 'for' in 'omp parallel for' to continue with the loop. 
This affects the performance of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used like you said but this is not something good to have if I were you and want to avoid fork/join with each iteration I would do it like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(j loop)
{
   for(i loop)
   {
        //Modify your code if necessary.
   }
}
```

in the above snippet if your maximum thread count is 10 and your j length is 100 then there will be 10 threads each will run 10 iterations of j.

Comment: THX, but I am sorry - I don't understand the problem you are pointing out. Can u explain more clearly please? Isn't it just a question of what parts of the calculation depend on on other parts? - If I get u correctly - it's just the matter that the 'i' values depend in previous 'i' locations, whereas the 'j' values don't - and therefor can be calculated parallely. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you suggesting to switch the order of the loops? Why?

Comment: The fork/join operations are long since implemented using thread pools and as such are much less expensive than the original implementations. Yet still it's better to keep them at the outmost level possible.

Comment: I am trying to help you to avoid starting threads and terminate them each iteration. by changing the program logic. Also if there is data dependency between iterations <threads> then you you should use some synchronization mechanism if you post more details about what you are trying to achieve I think I can help you more.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks for pointing that out yet OpenMP has different implementations. I am using the MS implementations but I believe you do not need to depend on that if you are trying to write a high performance program.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez, thanks, I try solving numerically a partial differential equation for - W(x,p,t), by using the Euler method for the numerical calculation. I want the get the solution as a metrix (*.txt file) whose rows are 'p' and lines - 'x', which will contain all the values of W(x,p) at time t_max. For that I need 3 loops: For (t=0;t<t_max;t+=1) --> for (x...) --> for (p...) --> {the numeric equation . ) . The last loop , I believe, is the only one that can be parrallelized. Am I being clear?

Comment: @MahmoudFayez, as a matter of fact, one is usually trying to depend on every available aspect of the system when writing a high performance program. Portability exists on paper only :)